# Have multiple version of an xml schema within the same definition file

Tags: xml, xsd

I'm developing the schema definition that carries a revision number. Is it possible to mark elements and groups as only being valid for specific revisions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not using XSD, no.  If I wanted to maintain multiple versions of a schema using a single source for shared constructs, I'd use some form of literate programming system, or (slightly more likely) invent a new form of literate programming system for the purpose.

[*Several hours later ...*]

One simple approach would be to use a `version` attribute in your own namespace on any schema construct that is to be included only for certain versions; the value of the `version` attribute would be a space-separated list of version identifiers.  For example:

```
<xs:schema targetNamespace="http://example.com/multiver"
  xmlns:mv="http://example.com/multiver">

  <xs:element name="e" mv:ver="1.0">
    <!--* 1.0 version of element 'e' *-->
  </xs:element>
  <xs:element name="e" mv:ver="1.1">
    <!--* 1.1 version of element 'e' *-->
  </xs:element>
  <xs:element name="f">
    <!--* element 'f' is not version-dependent ... *-->
  </xs:element>
  ...
</xs:schema>
```

It's simple to use XSLT or XQuery to extract just those declarations that carry an appropriate mv:ver value.

This simple-minded approach may get a bit tedious if the number of versions climbs above five or ten, and you may decide you want something that allows you to say things like "up through version 3.2" and "from version 3.3 to version 4.34, inclusive".  The conditional-inclusion attributes described in [section 4.2.2 of XSD 1.1](http://www.w3.org/TR/xmlschema11-1/#cip) illustrate one possible way of approaching that problem.